# Why isn't my DeleteNode() function working?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have created a singly linked list with 3 nodes having values 45,90,100 respectively. I'm writing a function that will delete the last node of the list. But the output prints all 3 values.

```
void DeleteNode()
{
    struct node *ptr1=head,*ptr2=head;
        while(ptr1!=NULL&&ptr2->link!=NULL)
```

> I have created two pointers ptr1 and ptr2 of struct node type for traversal. The loop is defined to run until ptr1 reaches last node and points to NULL and ptr2->link i.e. the last node points to NULL.

```
{
    ptr1=ptr1->link;
    ptr2=ptr2->link;
}
ptr2=NULL;
```

> When the loop breaks, ptr2 will point to NULL and hence the last node should get deleted. But that doesn't happen.

```
}
```

Comment: What do you think ptr2=NULL does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"ptr2 will point to NULL and hence the last node should get deleted."*

Nope.

You nullify a pointer that is a local variable (that happens to point to something in the linked list before you nullify it), and **not** a link pointer part of the linked list structure: it has no effect on the linked list.

Note that once this is corrected, you will have a memory leak (the removed node).

Also, ptr1 and ptr2 always point to the same thing, it makes no sense to keep both. You probably had initially the idea to have ptr2==ptr1->link or the other way around, but it's not necessary and your test `ptr1 != NULL && ptr2->link != NULL` is really equivalent to `ptr1 != NULL && ptr1->link != NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr2` is a local variable of the function. Setting its value to `NULL` does not changes data members `link` of nodes of the list.

Moreover if the list contains only one node it will not be removed from the list because the global variable `head` will not be changed.

Using your approach (you did not show how the list is created) the function can look the following way

```
void DeleteNode( void )
{
    struct node *ptr1 = head;
    
    if ( ptr1 )
    {
        struct node *ptr2 = head->link;

        if ( ptr2 == NULL )
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while ( ptr2->link != NULL )
            {
                ptr1 = ptr1->link;
                ptr2 = ptr2->link;
            }

            ptr1->link = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
} *head;

void display( void )
{
    for ( struct node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->link )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }
    puts( "null" );
}

void DeleteNode( void )
{
    struct node *ptr1 = head;
    
    if ( ptr1 )
    {
        struct node *ptr2 = head->link;

        if ( ptr2 == NULL )
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while ( ptr2->link != NULL )
            {
                ptr1 = ptr1->link;
                ptr2 = ptr2->link;
            }

            ptr1->link = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node n3 = { 100, NULL };
    struct node n2 = {  90, &n3  };
    struct node n1 = {  45, &n2  };
    
    head = &n1;
    
    display();
    
    DeleteNode();
    display();
    
    DeleteNode();
    display();

    DeleteNode();
    display();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
45 -> 90 -> 100 -> null
45 -> 90 -> null
45 -> null
null
```

The function can be defined simpler if to access pointers in the list by reference. For example

```
void DeleteNode( void )
{
    struct node **current = &head;

    while ( *current && ( *current )->link )
    {
        current = &( *current )->link;
    }

    *current = NULL;
}
```

Pay attention to that the function does not free the removed node if it was allocated dynamically. In general case list consists of dynamically allocated nodes that such a function as `DeleteNode` shall free them.